# What is the equivelant to meson's subprojects/wrap files in cmake

Tags: cmake, meson-build

The meson concept of subprojects which is very useful, when combined with wrap files, for managing external dependencies without embedding the source into the projects.

While CMake does support dependencies, I can't find an equivalent to meson's when combined with wrap files and subprojects; the best I can find is either embedding the dependency into the project as a subproject or relying on having the dependency installed on the system.

Does CMake have something equivalent to meson's subproject + wrap, to deal with dependencies?

Comment: did you try to use the *ExternalProject_Add()* ?
src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: you also have *FetchContent* (configure time) for CMake >= 3.11
src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html

Comment: @Mizux Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.